# me/photos and albums not returning all photos

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph, photos

When I make a request to me/photos I should expect to get all photos that I've been tagged in.  However, I am not getting this behavior.  There seems to be a few pictures here and there that are missing from the JSON results.  When I go on FB, they are visible to me.

This is happening to some albums as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If a photo has privacy settings that are more restrictive than "everyone", these typically will not be returned by the API. They will be visible to you on the front end.

Comment: @cpilko - i don't think that's correct, if you're using a user's access token it should be able to retrieve anything visible to that user. what's much more likely is that the person who uplaoded the photo has blocked apps from accessing any of their data (less likely) or certain types of their data such as photos (more likely)

Comment: @Igy - I'll defer to you, since you're behind the looking glass. I can only poke and prod at the API and see what comes out.

Comment: You can check if the (photo uploader) user has disabled platform pretty easily with a call to /USER_ID here, but there's no way i know of to check their 'how friends can bring my data to apps they use' setting

Comment: @Igy - I'm having this, too. I can provide more info if you're curious? Happens with both 'me/photos' and FQL queries (they match, but are different than what I see when logged in). It's only about ~10 out of my 425 photos - HOWEVER, on 'photos I'm tagged in', it's more like 20% of all photos..

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook's App Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) page allows users to change the exposure of their content to applications other people use.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vve6b.png

If I have prevented applications from viewing my photos, when you login to a Facebook application you will not be able to see any photos I have uploaded.  This is still the case even if I have tagged you in my photos.

If you, however, visit the Facebook website directly you will be able to see all the photos you have been tagged in.

This accounts for the discrepancy we have been seeing.

Tested using 2 Facebook accounts.